# WebView App crashes when clicking on Data Table Plugin export button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, android-webview

Hi i have a website using Data Tables plugin to show and export data in different formats like excel, csv and pdf. The website is running perfectly fine and buttons to export is also working. Now i have created WebView for the website, but whenever i click the export buttons from Data Tables plugin, the app crashes. I have given android downloader and permissions and have attached some screenshots of the code.
Using JQuery for Data Tables creation in website.

[Plugin](https://datatables.net/)

code Jquery datatable implement

```
$("#stationTable").DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    pageLength: 5,
    lengthChange: false,
    searching: true,
    ordering: false,
    //order: [0, 'asc']
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: ["csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"],
  });
```

code webview permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

code webview settings

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mywebView.setDownloadListener(new MyDownloadListener(this));
```

code webview android downloader

```
public class MyDownloadListener implements DownloadListener {

private Context mContext;

public MyDownloadListener(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
    // Create an intent to open the download URL in the browser
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

I am new to webview creation, so can you also explain the issue and solution. I want the android webview to work perfectly fine, the buttons to download the data exactly like in my website.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: good to know thanks its my first quest. @CBroe